# Sencha Architect not reflect with changes

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I'm using Sencha Architect to building Sencha Touch application.
The Architect not reflect code changes in it. It don't ask me something like "This file has been modified by another program....Do you want to reload it"

Does archtiect support this function ? How to enable it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, architect does not support this feature. All the changes you do to your source code must be done inside Sencha Architect.

Even if you try to edit the files, the first comment lines say:

```
/*
 * This file will be auto-generated each and everytime you save your project.
 *
 * Do NOT hand edit this file.
 */
```

The reason for that is when you make changes to your code, Architect also changes a structure in it's meta folder so all the components and properties show up in the right places with the right seetings. Editing this by hand may break this functionality leaving your project broken and unable to be loaded inside Architect.